# Flash animate 2017 scroll pane bug

Tags: flash, adobe, scrollpane, creative-cloud

Whenever i open my .Fla that has 3 scroll panes within it they appear to have been removed from library my question is does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix the issue? Thanks in advance.

First i add the scroll pane components to the screen [Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Ft5.png)

Then i save the project and close.When i reopen the project the components have been removed. [Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIUyQ.png)

UPDATE: so i tried deleting everything in my scene and library to do with the scroll-pane this appeared to resolve the issue for some time but it has since started again.

Comment: Not really, considering you've given us absolutely nothing to work with.